# How should I implement a watch method in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
function Demo(props：{count: number}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [a, setA] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    monitor(props.count, count, text, a);
  }, [props.count, count]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => setCount(c => c + 1)}
      >
        click
      </button>
      <input value={text} onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)} />
      <input value={a} onChange={e => setA(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  )
```

I tried to print the log when the properties.count and count changed, but eslint gave a warning
`React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'a' and 'text'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

how should I fix it

Comment: Can you post the complete function ?

Comment: Not every eslint rule is a good rule. If you know based on which dependencies you want to re-run the useEffect, and your eslint is telling you to do something else, perhaps the eslint rule is not good for your use-case.

Comment: The warning is clear, add `a` and `text` states to the dependencies of `useEffect`. It is equivalent to `componentDidUpdate` life cycle method of class component

Comment: @SARANSURYA I re-edited it and now give it up

Comment: @吴连雯 I think it is better to add the line "// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps", This should do the job, And only do this if you are sure that the params passed to the use Effect dependencies is valid.

Answer (score 0):

```js
useEffect(() => {
  monitor(props.count, count, text, a);
}, [props.count, count, text, a]);
```

or change `a` and `text` to refs